# Get PHP file using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to use javascript or jquery to get a html or php file and put its contents inside a div of the current page.

I know how to do this using ajax but would like to know if there is a simpler way without having to use all the code that ajax uses.

Comment: What "all the code"? An AJAX call with jquery is all of one line of code with about 3 or 4 arguments chained together.

Comment: "How do I do AJAX without AJAX because one line of code is too long?" >.<

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for jQuery's [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$('#div_id').load('url');
```

Comment: ninja'd! that always happens to me

Answer (score 2):

if `<div id='mydiv'></div>` is your target:

```
$('#mydiv').load('/address/to/page');
```

Should do the trick.